# How do I give col names for reduce way of merging data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dfs:- `df1` and `df2`.:-

```
dfs=[df1,df2]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='Serial_Nbr'), dfs)
```

I want to select only one column apart from the merge column `Serial_Nbr` in `df1`while doing the merge.
how do i do this..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter column in `df1`:

```
dfs=[df1[['Serial_Nbr']],df2]
```

Or if only 2 DataFrames remove `reduce`:

```
df_final =  pd.merge(df1[['Serial_Nbr']], df2, on='Serial_Nbr')
```

Comment: Thanks. I always forget  the double square brackets